# append array to querystring using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a table with list of jobs details and with checkbox for each job when i click the 
next page link with slecting the checkboxes so that i should get the query string with the checkbox values and links url query string

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=job_id>"
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=job_id>"
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=job_id>"
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=job_id>"
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=job_id>"


    <a href ='index.cgi?reqpage=$prev_page&job_category_id=$jobCategory' class='paginateAdmin' id='govtPaginate'>prevPage</a>


    function getJobsChecked(){ 
            var arr = [];
            var i= 0;
            $('.checkJobToSend:checked').each(function(){
                 arr[i++] = $(this).val();
            });   

            return arr;

      }

          $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click','.paginateAdmin',
            function(e){
              e.preventDefault();      
             var arr = getJobsChecked();

              var post = $(this).attr("href");
              var array = post.split('?');
          var id=$(this).attr('id');




    $.post(
        'job.cgi',
        array[1],
        function(data,status){

           switch(id)
            {
                case "nonItPaginate":

                     $('#nonit').html(data);

                    break;
                case "ItPaginate":

                         $('#it').html(data);
                        break;
                case "govtPaginate":

                     $('#govt').html(data);
                    break;
            default:

    }    

        }
    );

    });
     });
```

how can i form a queryString with array[1] and with an arr of checked box values like

```
reqpage=2&job_category_id=2&checkJob=1&checkJob=2&checkJob=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple parameters with the same name there can only be one parameter with `checkJob`. So you can do this instead:

```
reqpage=2&job_category_id=2&checkJob=1,2,3
```

Which can be achieved like this:

```
// get checked values
var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"].checkJobToSend:checked');    
var checkedValues = [];
checked.each(function(i) {

    // add checked values to our temporary list
     checkedValues.push(checked[i].value);        
});

// create query param
var queryParam = 'reqpage=2&job_category_id=2&checkJob=' + checkedValues.join(',');
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/GsSqc/

On your server-side code, it would have to interpret `checkJob=1,2,3`.

```
// in PHP
$jobs = explode(",", $_GET["checkJob"]);
echo $jobs[0];    // outputs value: 1
echo $jobs[1];    // outputs value: 2
echo $jobs[2];    // outputs value: 3
```

You can read more about the following functions used:

- `:checked` jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/
- `.join()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 0):

This will create your query string and add it to the hash (the hash part won't work on jsFiddle, or at least you won't see it change in the URL):

**Javascript**:

```
function getJobsChecked(){ 
            var arr = [];
            var i= 0;
            $('.checkJobToSend:checked').each(function(){
                 arr[i++] = $(this).val();
            });   
      return arr;
      }

$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    var arr = getJobsChecked();
    var qString = "reqpage=2&job_category_id=2";
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        qString+="&checkJob=" + arr[i];
    }
    location.hash=qString;
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="4" />2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="7" />3
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="12" />4
<input type="checkbox" class="checkJobToSend" name="checkJOb" value="5" />5
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Do It" />
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Zxhzq/